# Using config calls within function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to simplify my code in R. I specified pathways for my files in config file. Now I want to create a function that will load up 4 separate datasets and then output them as separate files. The data I am loading comes from SAS if that makes a difference.

I was able to write a function that reads one specific file, but I do not understand why it does not work for multiple files. Any advice would be much appreciated.

This is my first post here, so please have mercy! (I did my due diligence and couldn't find an answer!)

Here is my function:

```
get_sas_data <- function(filepath_fmt =      config::get("tblschemesfmt_filepath"),
                         filepath_usages =   config::get("tblusages_filepath"),
                         filepath_schemes =  config::get("tblschemes_filepath"),
                         filepath_users =    config::get("tblusers_filepath")) {
#initiate console
  cat("Retreiving Data...")
#1st table
  tblschemesfmt <-
    haven::read_sas(filepath_fmt) %>%
    janitor::clean_names()
  cat("tblschemesfmt loaded...")
#2nd table
  tblusages <-
    haven::read_sas(filepath_usages) %>%
    janitor::clean_names()
  cat("tblusages loaded...")
#3rd table
  tblschemes <-
    haven::read_sas(filepath_schemes) %>%
    janitor::clean_names()
  cat("tblschemes loaded...")
#4th table
  tblusers <-
    haven::read_sas(filepath_users) %>%
    janitor::clean_names()
  cat("tblusers loaded...")
  #create outputs
  tblschemes <<- tblschemes
  tblusers <<- tblusers
  tblusages <<- tblusages
  tblschemesfmt <<- tblschemesfmt
}
```

What I have tried:

1. Different variations of quotation marks (or lack of those)
2. I also tried something along the lines of:

```
get_sas_data <- function (x, filepath = config::get(x)) {      
  data <- haven::read_sas(filepath_schemes) %>%
    janitor::clean_names()
}
```

in hopes of creating a generic function that can be applied to any SAS dataset. I have failed miserably!